# Did Pakistan supply any military aid to Azerbaijan during the second Karabakh war?

Tags: war, pakistan

- [Pakistani troops fighting in Azerbaijan against Armenia, says report](https://zeenews.india.com/world/pakistani-troops-fighting-in-azerbaijan-against-armenia-says-report-2313361.html)
- [Pakistani troops fighting in Azerbaijan against Armenia, says report](https://www.livemint.com/news/world/pakistani-soldiers-fighting-alongside-azerbaijan-troops-11601354199941.html)

According to the above links, Pakistan sent soldiers to fight against Armenians.

- [Pakistan denies its army's presence in Azerbaijan](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/asia-pacific/pakistan-denies-its-armys-presence-in-azerbaijan/1993022)

Did Pakistan supply any military aid to Azerbaijan during the second Karabakh war?

Comment: The article in the 1st link has no details whatsoever, except of diplomatic declarations etc. So it seems trash talking.